# What's the benefit to allow multiple sockets to listen on the same port?

Tags: c, sockets, bind

In my own experience,I bind 1 socket and dispatch the requests to other threads.

But the famous web server nginx is `bind()` multiple sockets on the destination port.

What's the benefit to do it this way?

Comment: Uh? you should only be able to do that if you are binding to a different IP/interface. What you can do is `accept()` on several processes/threads, and the kernel will choose one, probably awakening only that one (avoiding the thundering herd problem).

Comment: @ninjalj ,that's not the case with nginx,it's binding multiple sockets to the same IP/interface.

Comment: It is typically not possible to bind multiple sockets to the same IP/Port pair at the same time.  `bind()` will fail with an error.  There is definately no benefit to doing so anyway even if it were possible.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through nginx source, I don't see that possibility.  To quote from the man page `ip(7)`

> When  a  process  wants  to  receive
>   new incoming packets or connections,
>   it should bind a socket to a local
>   interface address using bind(2).  Only
>   one IP
>          socket may be bound to any given local (address, port) pair.

So, I think that there is something else going on.  Can you mention how you determined that nginx was doing this?